# How to store high volume inner collections inside a document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

MongoDB has the restriction for a document to be max. 16MB in size. However, it's also encouraged to store related collections inside the document. For example, a blog post and its comments:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    title: "First Post",
    Content: "...",
    Comments: [
        { content: "..." },
        { content: "..." },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Assuming that this post has gone viral and I'm getting millions of comments. How should I store the comments in MongoDB? Should I put it inside another collection with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: 23,
    blogPostId: 1,
    content: "..."
}
```

If that's the case, how should I make the queries like "get me the blog posts which have more than 10 comments" perform efficiently?

Comment: It is encouraged to store related collecitons/relations as subdocuments when it is fit to. If you have a high volumne relation it is one of the clauses that is not fit for subdocuments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common use case for MongoDB and is covered in the [online manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/). You typically have 3 choices:

1. Store each comment in separate document
2. Embed all comments in the parent document (be sensitive to the 16MB limit)
3. A hybrid design, stores comments separately from the parent but aggregates comments into a small number of documents (buckets), where each contains many comments

You could probably also consider another type of hybrid, where you have a max number of comments stored in an array of the parent document and then maybe use bucketed comments in a 'comments overflow' collection, which would only be used by those posts that have gone viral. In reality, only a small ratio of visitors would ever interact with the web app to result in a query against the overflow docs. It's sort of a trade-off of runtime efficiency Vs developer complexity.

For most of these options, you would maintain "pre-aggregated" summary data (eg. total number of comments) in the parent document and this would be what you would be able to query on easily. Pre-aggregation is also discussed in the [online manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/).

Answer (score 1):

Well,I would go for a simple and efficient solution.Let's view the problem from a query point of view. Most queries are interested in the most recent comments, right?. We do agree that embedding documents is quite fast and efficient in MongoDB but we are limited to a certain document size. Therefore a compromise is needed here. 
We can embed the most recent comments and reference the rest.

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(...),
  title : "Post title",
  most_recent_comments:[
  {
    commentBody :"...",
    author : "...",
  },
  {
    commentBody :"...",
    author : "...",
  },
  ],
  all_comments_ids :[ObjectId(commentId),ObjectId(commentId),ObjectId(commentId)]
}
```

So, you can create a designated `collection` for comments and keep the most recent as embedded . From your programme recent comments could be a `queue` with a limited size you specify.